# How to use if/else to show different date formats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried this:

```
<% if quantified.averaged %>
  <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b %Y") %>
<% else %>
  <%= result.date_value.strftime("%d %b %Y") %>
<% end %>
```

but I get an `NoMethodError in Pages#home` for `.averaged`.

This is being rendered by:

```
<h2>Averaged</h2>
  <%= render @averaged_quantifieds %>
<% end %>
<h2>Instance</h2>
  <%= render @instance_quantifieds %>
<% end %>
```

which comes from the **pages_controller.rb**

```
def home
  @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
  @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
end
```

When a user goes to the _form they click on either averaged or instance to track their stat. If they click on averaged, AJAX will show the date_field as month & day, if they click on instance, AJAX will show day, month, and year.

How can we show this difference in pages#home? It works in the quantifieds index.

Thank you for your expertise!

### RESPONSE TO COMMENTS

```
undefined method `averaged' for #<Quantified:0x007fa2c6e932a0>
```

```html
activemodel (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
app/views/quantifieds/_quantified.html.erb:17:in `block in _app_views_quantifieds__quantified_html_erb___3328560064722378575_70168563277280'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
app/views/quantifieds/_quantified.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_quantifieds__quantified_html_erb___3328560064722378575_70168563277280'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:436:in `block in collection_with_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:432:in `map'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:432:in `collection_with_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:324:in `render_collection'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `block in render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:305:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
haml (4.0.6) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:12:in `render_with_haml'
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:51:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb___3717821255907924551_70168609998100'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

**quantified.rb**

```
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :results #correct
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true #correct
    scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'Averaged') }
    scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'Instance') }
    validates :categories, :metric, :results, presence: true
    acts_as_taggable

    CATEGORIES = ['Averaged', 'Instance']
end
```

Comment: I think the error you reported is in the line `@averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged`. Can you copy and past the error message?

Comment: You also need to show us the code for the "averaged" scope which I assume is a scope on the "Quantified" model (if I'm guessing correctly... you haven' told us how the code for the models is structured)

Comment: @TarynEast you're correct. Updated with full quantified model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling method `averaged` on an instance of Qualified in the line `<% if quantified.averaged %>`. You cannot do that because you do not have an instance method called `averaged`. To know if an instance is "averaged" you need to test its categories. Something like this:

```
<% if quantified.categories == "Averaged" %>
  <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b %Y") %>
<% else %>
  <%= result.date_value.strftime("%d %b %Y") %>
<% end %>
```

Or you can create an instance method to test this:

```
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def averaged?
    categories == "Averaged"
  end
  # ...
end
```

Once did that, you can do this:

```
<% if quantified.averaged? %>
  <%= result.date_value.strftime("%b %Y") %>
<% else %>
  <%= result.date_value.strftime("%d %b %Y") %>
<% end %>
```

An improvement is to create a method called `formatted_date_value` on the model to remove this flow from the view.

Comment: Thank you so much for this insightful answer!

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem with your sample at the top of the page (ie what the error is complaining about) is that you're calling `averaged` on an *instance* of a Quantified. and the `average` scope has to be called on a collection of quantifieds.

What you're doing in the controller is correct usage of the `averaged` method.

if you need the collection, use the variable you set up in the controller.

if you want it on an individual, you probably wanted:

(note question mark)... also - make sure you actually write an `averaged?` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was playing around with your suggestion, which shed some light, but I had to go with dx7 here for the multiple options he presented.